# How can I access the sub-items of a <svg:use> tag from javascript?

Tags: javascript, xhtml, svg

I have the following SVG code in a XHTML page

```
<svg:svg>
<svg:svg width="450" heigth="450" viewBox="0 0 500 500">  
    <svg:defs>
        <svg:g id='mygroup'>
            <svg:circle id='a' cx="15" cy="15" r='15' fill="green" fill-opacity="0.3"/>
            <svg:line id='b' x1="15" y1="15" x2="15" y2="0" style="stroke: black;" />
        </svg:g>
</svg:defs>

<svg:rect width="400" height="400" fill="white" stroke="black" />
<svg:use id="g1" xlink:href="#mygroup" x="100" y="100" onclick="moveMe()" />
<svg:use id="g2" xlink:href="#mygroup" x="100" y="200" />
</svg:svg>
```

and I would like to modify it with the following javascript code

```
<script><![CDATA[
    function moveMe(){
    obj = document.getElementById("g1");
    obj.setAttributeNS(null, "x", "200"); //Ok it works

    //How can I change the color of the a circle in g1? 
    obj = document.getElementById("g1.a");
    obj.setAttributeNS(null, "fill", "red"); //It doesn't work
    }
 ]]></script>
```

How can I change the color of the 'a' circle in 'g1'? How can I access it from my javascript code?

EDIT: If I have a 2nd mygroup item called g2, I don't want to change its color.

Comment: I'm not an svg expert but from the looks of things, your JavaScript is manipulating the DOM, which is the non-expanded form, so no, you can't change mygroup and have it apply to g1 but not g2. You will have to create a copy of mygroup, and attach g1 to one copy and g2 to the other one. Then you can manipulate them independently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution is to pass in a color using the 'currentColor' keyword like this:

```
<svg:svg>
<svg:svg width="450" heigth="450" viewBox="0 0 500 500">  
<svg:defs>
    <svg:g id='mygroup'>
        <svg:circle id='a' cx="15" cy="15" r='15' fill="currentColor" fill-opacity="0.3"/>
        <svg:line id='b' x1="15" y1="15" x2="15" y2="0" style="stroke: black;" />
    </svg:g>
</svg:defs>

<svg:rect width="400" height="400" fill="white" stroke="black" />
<svg:use id="g1" xlink:href="#mygroup" x="100" y="100" onclick="moveMe()" color="green"/>
<svg:use id="g2" xlink:href="#mygroup" x="100" y="200" color="blue"/>
</svg:svg>
```

If you want to change the colors you can now just change the 'color' attribute on the 'use' elements. Or simply use CSS to do it, e.g:

```
<style>
#g1:hover { color: lime }
</style>
```

Comment: nice! I didn't knew that one. But one thing: in your example you cannot define a default color for the circles. E.g. you want to have all #a green, and only by clicking #g1 it should turn red. Is this possible?

Comment: It works perfectly. Thank you so much for this elegant solution

Comment: @räph: It's possible to apply the default color with CSS, so that all use-elements that has a particular classname gets the default 'color' set, e.g: .myInstances { color: fuchsia; /* the default color */ }

This way you only need to set the color once, instead of on each 'use' element.

As for the clicking, well, maybe if the state-change is non-static you could use an :active pseudoclass to set it, but it might be better to assign an additional classname instead when clicked.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
obj = document.getElementById("g1.a");
```

with

```
obj = document.getElementById("a");
```

since the id of the circle element is *a* and not *g1.a*.

iN document.getElementById(id)

```
id is a case-sensitive string representing the unique ID of the element 
being sought.
```

Comment: Thnaks for this answer. That works in the original example but see my edit.

Comment: I think you are calling the moveme function on g1's click only. Then what is the issue for g2.

Comment: In fact, the problem is that the color is changing on g1 and g2. I would like to change it only for g1. Is that possible?

Comment: Are you calling the function on both g1 and g2?

Comment: No only on g1. What I want to do is to change the color of the circle in g1 without modifying the circle in g2.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the desired behaviour by using css.

Add this to your html-head:

```
<style type="text/css">
   .g1red #a {fill:red}
</style>
```

use this script code:

```
<script><![CDATA[
function moveMe(){
obj = document.getElementById("g1");
obj.setAttributeNS(null, "x", "200");
obj.setAttributeNS(null, "class", "g1red");  
}
]]></script>
```